# Git is changing tar file with a driver

Tags: git, binaryfiles

I'm working on a project which includes uploading a .tar.gz file which contains a driver. I upload the file to git and for a time, everything seems fine. However, after some time passes Git consistently changes the tar file with the driver in a predictable way. I just can't figure out why. Below is my .gitattributes file. My best guess is it has something to do with that, perhaps something about line endings, but I'm not sure.

```
# Auto detect text files and perform LF normalization
* text eol=lf

# Custom for Visual Studio
*.cs     diff=csharp

# Standard to msysgit
*.doc    diff=astextplain
*.DOC    diff=astextplain
*.docx diff=astextplain
*.DOCX diff=astextplain
*.dot  diff=astextplain
*.DOT  diff=astextplain
*.pdf  diff=astextplain
*.PDF    diff=astextplain
*.rtf    diff=astextplain
*.RTF    diff=astextplain

# Set tar files to be treated as binary
*.tar  binary
*.tar* binary
*.rpm  binary
*.png  binary

jq      binary
ripmime binary
```

Comment: in *what* predictable way is the file changed? And: git doesn't usually change files at all, it's always *commits* that are linked to a change, so where does that change happen / how do you notice it?

Comment: Probably not what you want, but why don't you upload the driver to somewhere else and include the download of it in the compilation/execution/whatever script via wget or curl?

Comment: Jens - hahaha no, I have a bunch of ways I could not use git, but that's not my objective.

Marcus - I'm not sure, but the MD5sum after the change is always the same and the tar file package will always decompress up to the same point before reporting it is broken.